# Multiple ForEach in same List vs. Multiple Lists with one ForEach

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I am new to iOS and SwiftUI and am playing around with making a "goals" app.  The code I'm referencing is a simple list, with incomplete goals listed on top of goals that have been marked complete.  I ran into this interesting problem when trying to put several `ForEach`s inside the same `List`.

When I used the code below, tapping on an incomplete goal (from the first foreach) would move that goal to below the Boundary, but the `GoalView()` constructor would not re-run, so the goal still appeared to be incomplete, and moreover, it still retained the original closure (`goal.markComplete()`), which would cause a crash. It's worth noting that `today` is an `@ObservedObject`, and it is updated by the calls to `markComplete()` and `markIncomplete()`

```
List {
    ForEach(today.incompleteGoals, id: \.id) { goal in
        GoalView(goal: goal, isCompleted: false)
            .onTapGesture { goal.markComplete() }
    }}
    Text("---Boundary---")
    ForEach(today.completedGoals, id: \.id) { goal in
        GoalView(goal: goal, isCompleted: true)
            .onTapGesture { goal.markIncomplete() }
    }}
}
```

However, when I switch to using two stacked lists (see below), the problem goes away. Tapping to complete a goal moves it to the bottom list, and the `GoalView()` constructor runs, changing the appearance and behavior of the goal.

```
VStack {
    List {
        ForEach(today.incompleteGoals, id: \.id) { goal in
            GoalView(goal: goal, isCompleted: false)
                .onTapGesture { goal.markComplete() }
    }}}
    Text("---Boundary---")
    List {
        ForEach(today.completedGoals, id: \.id) { goal in
            GoalView(goal: goal, isCompleted: true)
                .onTapGesture { goal.markIncomplete() }
    }}}
}
```

What is the fundamental difference that would cause this bottom implementation to re-run the `GoalView()` in the `ForEach` closure whereas the top impl. doesn't?  I'm especially confused about why both implementations move a completed goal to below the Boundary, despite the top one not seeming to ever execute the closure attached to the second `ForEach`.  Any explanation / tips would be much appreciated!

EDIT: `today` (type `Day`) and `goal` (type `Goal`) are both `NSManagedObject`s / CoreData entities. Included below is the my definition for `completedGoals` from an extension to `Day`, which should shed light on how the two are defined and related.  Each `Day` has relationships called `completedGoals_` and `incompleteGoals_` which are unordered sets of Goals linked to that Day.

```
var completedGoals: Array<Goal> {
    get {
        let result = (completedGoals_ as? Set<Goal>) ?? []
        return Array(result).sorted(by: ...)
    }
    set { completedGoals_ = Set(newValue) as NSSet } 
}
```

and here is the rough implementation of `markComplete()` from an extension to `Goal` (`daysThatDidntComplete_` is the inverse relationship to `completedGoals_`, and same with incomplete):

```
func markComplete(on day: Day, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    // ...check & crash if self (goal) wasn't already incomplete on day
    removeFromDaysThatDidntComplete_(day)  // provided by CoreData
    addToDaysThatCompleted_(day)  // provided by CoreData
    try? context.save()
}
```

Comment: Would you show today's type and goal's type?

Comment: Yes, both are CoreData entities -- NSManagedObject. I edited the original post with the relevant extensions I added.

Answer (score 0):

Code is not testable for me, so just an idea - try the following

```
List {
    ForEach(today.incompleteGoals, id: \.id) { goal in
        GoalView(goal: goal, isCompleted: false)
            .onTapGesture { 
                goal.markComplete() 
                self.today.objectWillChange.send()     // << here !!
            }
    }}
    Text("---Boundary---")
    ForEach(today.completedGoals, id: \.id) { goal in
        GoalView(goal: goal, isCompleted: true)
            .onTapGesture { 
                goal.markIncomplete() 
                self.today.objectWillChange.send()     // << here !!
            }
    }}
}
```

Comment: No luck.  Same with adding goal.objectWillChange().send() (and both)